# Почему выравнивание здесь работает не так как ожидается

Tags: c++, struct

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    char x;
    int y;
    int z;

};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(Foo);
}
```

Сделал иллюстрацию как выше выглядит выравнивание:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь все выходит, но не понимаю почему происходит выравнивание в коде ниже:

```
struct Foo
{
  int x;
  int y;
  char z;
};
```

с `int`- ми все ясно, но вот `char`, он последний и весит 1 байт, по идее не должен выравнивается

Comment: Потому что если сделать из них массив.

Comment: @Qwertiy не понял, о чём вы?

Comment: `Foo x[4];` - где будет `x[1].x`?

Comment: Сделайте массив `Foo arr[2];`. Если компилятор не добавит в конец структуры байты заполнения, то второй элемент массива `arr[1]` окажется не выровнен. Можно было бы добавить байты заполнения между элементами массива, но стандарт запрещает такое. Каждый элемент массива должен следовать непосредственно за своим предшественником, поэтому компилятор вынужден раздувать сам элемент массива.

Comment: Если Вас не устраивает выравнивание по размеру слова, то используйте #pragma pack(push, 1) struct{...} #pragma pack(pop) Читайте подробнее https://habr.com/ru/post/142662/  "он последний и весит 1 байт, по идее не должен выравнивается" - должен, если ему не сказать об этом

Comment: @Qwertiy если из них даже сделать массив с pragma 1 структура будет упакована по количеству байт, отнють не из-за массива по умолчанию пакуется с выравниванием, а для скорости доступа к элементам структуры

Comment: @Виктор, при чём тут скорость доступа? Ты про скорость доступа к невыровненным данным? На некоторых платформах такое вообще запрещено.

Comment: @Qwertiy  для скорости доступа к элементам структуры. А на каких платформах запрещено? Если так, то как обрабатывать пакеты, приходящие от устройств ввода/вывода? Вероятно, Вы ошибаетесь на этот счёт

Comment: @Виктор для процессоров x64 шина может и по 8 байт передать за подход? то - есть упаковка может и по 8 байт(double word) быть?

Comment: @Kurr200 да, на x64 char выровняется в структуре в 8байт - это факт (если не указать другой pack)

Comment: @Виктор если pack стоит 4 байта например нужно выровнять 8 - байтовый тип, то процессоре придётся выполнить  2 операции?

Comment: @Виктор, на всех, кроме x86.

Comment: @Виктор, *`на x64 char выровняется в структуре в 8байт`*, и как вы это проверяли? Обратите внимание --  `struct x {int a, b, char c;};` sizeof(struct x) == 12 (не кратно 8) (если же говоря о выравнивании char поля в структуре вы имели в виду выравнивание самого поля, то посмотрите на `struct s {short x; char c;}` (ее sizeof будет 4, а поле `s.c` размещается сразу за полем `s.x`))

Comment: @Qwertiy, по крайней мере в 64-бит ARM невыровненный доступ также обычно разрешен (можно выключить, но Linux это не делает)

Comment: @Kurr200 Что Вы имеете ввиду по поводду 2-х операций? Структура выравнивается при компиляции. Значения из структуры выбираются в зависимости от типа процессора.